# Как собрать список url статей с сайта в массив?

Tags: javascript, node.js, парсер

Есть такой код он парсит данные с сайта и записывает их в виде массива.

Вопрос : сейчас ссылки для парсинга подставляються в массив руками, а сейчас мне нужно написать цикл как раз чтобы собрать массив из url. Я только никак не могу понять мне не известен не один url как должен выглядеть такой цикл?

```js
const tress = require('tress');
const needle = require("needle");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const async = require("async");
const fs = require('fs');

let aUrl = [
    // Здесь нужно написать цикл который будет собирать все url в массив
    'ссылка на товар',
    'ссылка на товар',
    'ссылка на товар',
];

const jquery = body => cheerio.load(body);

let products = [];

let parsePage = ($) => {
    let name = $("#shop-production-view > h1").first().text();
    let categories = $(".breadcrumb").text();
    let price = $(".price").text();
    let content = $('.content_item').html();
    let images = $(".image").find("img").attr("src");

    // let $imageLink = $(".shop-production-view .image a"),
    //     img = '';
    // if ($imageLink.length > 0) {
    //     img = $imageLink.attr("href");
    // }


    products.push({
        name,
        categories,
        content,
        price,
        images,
        // img,
    });
};

let q = tress((url, callback) => {
    needle.get(url, {  }, (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }

        parsePage(jquery(res.body));

        callback();
    });
}, 5);

q.drain = () => {
    console.log(products);
};

for (let i = 0; i < aUrl.length; i++) {
    q.push(aUrl[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё что нужно было сделать с данным выше кодом. Теперь в корне проекта появляется json файл нужный мне

```js
q.drain = () => {
    // console.log(products);

    fs.writeFile('data.json', JSON.stringify(products), (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;

    console.log("saved");
});
```

Comment: Вы бы определились сначала. То вам нужно в массив сохранить как **json**, то как **csv** в csv.

Comment: @Dan проблема с сохранением спарсеных данных решена!!! 
Тему отредактировал уже сейчас нужно решить вопрос как собрать url статей с сайта в массив

Comment: Если так резко меняете тему вопроса - лучше создайте отдельный вопрос, иначе это вводит в замешательство. Человек о чём-то одном спросил, ему отвечали, потом он спрашивает о другом... Новые люди, зайдя сюда и прочитав ответы, вообще не поймут, почему мы это писали (отвечали так).

Comment: @Dan да, вы правы

Answer (score 1):

Готовый (рабочий) пример сохранения JS-массива в csv-файл:

```js
// исходный массив, который хотим увидеть в csv файле
var data = [
  ["name 1", 2, 3],
  ["name 2", 4, 5],
  ["name 3", 6, 7],
  ["name 4", 8, 9],
  ["name 5", 10, 11]
];

// массив строк для csv файла
var lineArray = [];

// пройти по исходному массиву и подготовить массив строк для csv файла
data.forEach(function(infoArray) {
  var line = infoArray.join(",");
  lineArray.push(line);
});
// контент - это строка, в которой наши подготовленные строки разделены \n
var csvContent = lineArray.join("\n"); // \n - переход на новую строку

// имя файла и blob - для создания файла csv
var filename = 'test.csv';
var blob = new Blob([csvContent], {
  type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;' // тип файла
});

// сохранить файл на диск
if (navigator.msSaveBlob) { // для IE 10+
  navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
} else { // для остальных браузеров
  var link = document.createElement("a");
  if (link.download !== undefined) {
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link.setAttribute("href", url);
    link.setAttribute("download", filename);
    link.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
  }
}
```

Ссылки на источники:

- [How to export JavaScript array info to csv (on client side)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24922761/5275890)
- [JavaScript array to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18849208/5275890)

Answer (score 0):

Испольузйте соответствующую библиотеку, например [fast-csv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-csv)

Примеры из документации:

```
var ws = fs.createWriteStream("my.csv");
csv
   .write([
       ["a", "b"],
       ["a1", "b1"],
       ["a2", "b2"]
   ], {headers: true})
   .pipe(ws);
```

,

```
csv
   .writeToPath("my.csv", [
       ["a", "b"],
       ["a1", "b1"],
       ["a2", "b2"]
   ], {headers: true})
   .on("finish", function(){
       console.log("done!");
   });
```

Больше примеров [тут](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-csv).